# Changing Image When Button Is Pressed - iOS - Xcode

Tags: ios, image, button

I am trying to change an image to another random image when a button is pressed.

I have uploaded 5 images to my "Supporting Files" and I now need to reference them.

1. I need to create an array which holds all of the images.
2. I create a button that will run a method when is clicked.
3. This method will choose a random number of the array and then display that image.

Can someone please give me some sample code for the 3 things I need to do.

(Please note I will also be needing to display text underneath the images in a label field and it will have to be linked to the image being displayed)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

take an array like this in viewDidLoad method,take three global variables imagesArray,titlesArray and

imageview

```
  imagesArray = [NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"image1.png",@"image2.png",@"image3.png",@"image4.png",@"image5.png" nil];
  titlesArray = [NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"title1",@"title2",@"title3",@"title4",@"title5" nil];
    -(IBAction)randomImage:(id)sender{
        int n= arc4random() % [imagesArray count];
        imageview.image= [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:n]];
        label.text=[titlesArray objectAtIndex:n];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSMutableArray * imagenames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"image1.png",@"image2.png",@"image3.png",@"image4.png",@"image5.png", nil];

NSMutableArray * Images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i=0;i<imagenames.count;i++)
{
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagenames objectAtIndex:i]];
    [Images addObject:image];
}

int n= arc4random() % 5;
if(n<Images.count)
{
    UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[Images objectAtIndex:n]];
}
```